# jQuery scroll takeover, scroll in sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've seen one or two sites lately that take over the default scrolling in browsers.

When scrolling down, it will animate a scroll down to the next content section (stopping any scroll events during the animation.

When scrolling up, the same thing happens, but to the previous section.

The site I currently have is here: http://cirkut.net/sub/proven/parallax/

I've got the parallax down, but I can't think of an easy way to takeover the scroll and animate this.  I'm fairly certain there must be a js/jQuery plugin to do this (I'm currently using `stellar.js`).

I've been searching for hours to find the example of what I want, but I can't find anything.  If I find one, I'll come back and edit this.

Thanks for any leads or help!

Comment: What about jQuery ScrollTo, http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: I can easily set scroll points and have it animate to where I want to go (See my example).  I don't want people to be able to freely scroll.  I want to limit them to (in this case 4) specific sections of the page.  When scrolling down, I want it to determine the closest slide and animate to that while preventing the default scrolling mechanism.

Comment: If you have everything inside of a `<div>` I think you should be able to accomplish this and override the browser setting.

Comment: I figure that I can probably create a jQuery plugin that accepts a couple options (the class name[s] you want to jump to, as well as whether you want to prevent default scroll or not).  It'll probably be a global function call like `$.blockScroll(options); I'll be working on it and post it back here unless someone posts something accomplishing what I want done.  Thanks :)

Comment: Nice on the jQuery plug-in.  I'm sure other people will want to use it also.